# Using OleDBDataReader to read Excel not retrieving all of a header column cells content

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdatareader

I have an Excel sheet that I am using to populate data in a Database. It seems as though there is only a certain number of characters that the OleDBDataReader actually reads in from a column heading before truncating the rest.

Is there a way around this?

How I am retrieving the column headings:

```
OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]",
OleDbConnection);
OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);

foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
{
string columnName = column.ColumnName;
}
```

Expected result: Targeted programs to address the welfare needs of students. E.g `breakfast clubs`

Actual Result: Targeted programs to address the welfare needs of students. E.g `br`

I have also tried using the `reader.GetName(i)` method to retrieve the information with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 characters is the column header limit of the Jet Engine reader.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/2fb51d81-3d64-445f-806a-519861b561ba/

Sorry I cannot find a better reference.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a feeling it was something like that.